# minify css/js into their individual files

Tags: javascript, gulp, dependencies

I have this default gulp file from a Visual Studio template:

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='clean, minPreBuild' />
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify");

var webroot = "./wwwroot/";

var paths = {
    js: webroot + "js/**/*.js",
    minJs: webroot + "js/**/*.min.js",
    css: webroot + "css/**/*.css",
    minCss: webroot + "css/**/*.min.css",
    concatJsDest: webroot + "js/_site.min.js",
    concatCssDest: webroot + "css/_site.min.css"
};

gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatJsDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.concatCssDest, cb);
});

gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min:css", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css"]);
gulp.task("minPreBuild", ["min:js", "min:css"]);
```

The problem I'm having is one of my js files in the directory has a dependency on knockout, but I'm only using knockout on one of the pages on the site. I don't want to include knockout on my shared view, and the default bundling all files into a single file causes a JS error "ko is undefined" as one of the JS files is dependent on KO.

Is there a way that I can minify files individually, without concatting it into the main "site.min.css"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to exclude the Knockout file from your `min:js` task. Prepending a path with `!` tells gulp to ignore that file:

```
gulp.task("min:js", function () {
  return gulp.src([
        paths.js, 
        "!" + paths.minJs,
        "!js/path/to/knockout.js" // don't include knockout in _site.min.js
      ], { base: "." })
    .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
```

Then you need to create a new task `min:knockout` that does nothing but minify your Knockout file. You'll probably want the minified file to end with a `.min.js` extension so you'll have to install the [`gulp-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) plugin as well.

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task("min:knockout", function () {
  return gulp.src("js/path/to/knockout.js", { base: "." })
    .pipe(rename("js/_knockout.min.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
```

Finally you need to make sure your new `min:knockout` task is executed when running the `min` and `minPreBuild` tasks:

```
gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:knockout", "min:css"]);
gulp.task("minPreBuild", ["min:js", "min:knockout", "min:css"]);
```

Comment: sorry I think I was unclear, it's not knockout itself i'm minifying that's problematic, it's one of my site's js files that references knockout functionality.  This one page has a knockout depedency, so I don't want it to get bundled into the "main.js", as then knockout will need to be included on every page as to avoid "blog.js" throwing an error w/ its dependency on knockout.  Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: So what? Doesn't really make a difference. Just means that you have to exclude that one JavaScript file instead of `knockout.js`. My answer above still applies.